# Angular validation not working until the second time i trigger it?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, form-control

JS.

```
const group = this.fb.group({ startDate : new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),
dateNotRequired: new FormControl(false)});

this.subs.add(group.get("dateoNotRequired").valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
if (value) {
group.get("startDate").setValidators(null);
group.get("startDate").updateValueAndValidity();
}));
```

Html:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="app.form.controls.startDate.touched && app.form.controls.startDate.errors?.required"> Start date is required</mat-error>
```

Functionality:
I have a toggle button on the front page where if i click it, it will make "Start Date" field a non-required field, otherwise I get validation message of "start date required".
What I noticed is if I toggle the button the first time, it reaches the subscribe and it recognizes "value" as true and clears the validation. HOWEVER, the error message still persists. IF  I toggle the button to "off" and then "on" again, the validation disappears.
I don't know why it takes two toggles of on-off-on to make the validation disappear as it should.

Comment: I just jumped into the same, did you find the reason for this?